# How to Convert Object into Serialized Object in MVC Controllers

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I Post the Following object and my Controllers Page Get the String Format How to I Convert Serialized Object in c#.

```
 [HttpPost]
   public object StoreCheckList(object ChkList)
    {

    }

[{"Remarks": "Teat","CountryId": 1,"ClientId": 1,"FacilityId": 1,"SpaceId":2},{"Remarks": "Teat","CountryId": 1,"ClientId": 1,"FacilityId":1,"SpaceId": 5}]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of MVCs built in support for strongly typed model binding. First, create a class with properties matching the input object

e.g.

```
public class StoreCheckListModel {
    public string Remarks {get;set;}
    public int CountryId {get;set;}
    public int ClientId {get;set;}
    public int FacilityId {get;set;}
    public int SpaceId {get;set;}
}
```

Then change your Mvc action to:

```
[HttpPost]
public object StoreCheckList(StoreCheckListModel[] ChkList) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Newtonsoft.Json, like so:

```
YourObjectType obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourObjectType>(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

As the name suggests, MVC is Model, View Controller. Your question is about how do I handle my posted request in controller.

But before handling that in your controller, you have to make sure that your `Model` and `View` are designed to match this pattern.

It looks like you are not using a `Model`. So first of all, create a model like below.

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Remarks { get; set; }
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public int FacilityId { get; set; }
    public int SpaceId { get; set; }
}
```

Change your controller method like this,

```
[HttpPost]
public object StoreCheckList(IEnumerable<MyModel> chkList)
{
    List<MyModel> myCheckList = chkList.ToList();
    ///do what you want to do
}
```

This should work as it is without any serialization related codes.